# ant design pagination - How to change default arrows (Down, Left, Right)

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am trying to change the ant design arrows in the pagination component to use FontAwesome Icons. After combing through the docs and scouring the internet, I have been unable to find a solution.

```
              <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={newData}
                loading={historyPaymentsIsLoading}
                showSorterTooltip={false}
                rowKey={(record) => record.rowId}
                scroll={{ x: 'max-content' }}
                onChange={handlePaginationChange}
                pagination={{
                    showSizeChanger: true,
                    showQuickJumper: true,
                    defaultPageSize: 25,
                    pageSizeOptions: ['25', '50', '100'],
                    position: ['bottomLeft'],
                    size: 'default',
                 
                }}
```

[image: Pagination]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the icons with `itemRender` props , please check this codeSandBox
https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-settings-antd-4-21-6-forked-0422vs

Comment: Thank you Faizal! That fixed the Left and Right arrow issue however, the border around the arrow is now gone. I am also trying to do the same thing to the down pagination arrow.

Comment: I added an image with the current state